# How to replace an image in a cell CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I created the collection programmatically. Everything works perfectly. But now I need to replace a picture in a certain cell. How to identify the cell and get to the UIImage?

```
var imagesOfPaletes = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if imagesOfPaletes == [] {
        for i in 0...11 {
            let palete = UIImage(named: "\(i)-0")!
            imagesOfPaletes.append(palete)
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    
    let img2 = imagesOfPaletes[indexPath.item]
    imageView2.image = img2
    myCell.contentView.addSubview(imageView2)
    
    return myCell
}
```

Comment: Generally if you need to reload a cell, you'd call one of the collectionView reload methods.

Comment: I can't tell from the code that you've included -- that's something only you can determine from whatever logic it is that your program uses.

Comment: You which image you put in cell with specific indexPath so you can be able to compute the indexPath of the cell where to update image and reload it

Comment: How can I reload it into this particular cell? Is there any method for set an image into the UIImage by Index Path

Comment: tableView.reloadRows(at:[indexParh of cell with new image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to access a certain cell use "collection.cellForItem(at: inedexPath)" and then use the returned cell object to access the image.

So to access the image you can loop through cells subviews using "collectionCell.subViews" and check the type of the subView. check the following example:-

```
let collectionCell = UICollectionViewCell()
collectionCell.addSubview(UIImageView())
for subView in collectionCell.subviews {
    if subView is UIImageView {
            debugPrint("Ok")
        }
    debugPrint("subview is \(subView)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got to the cell. But I can’t get to ImageView, which is programmatically placed on it! How to do it????????

Comment: Hi Sash, check the answer edit.